# Making separate plots with unique identifiers in Python using CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a CSV file where one column has a unique identifier (a,b,c...) and I would like to make separate plots based on this identifier (so a separate line on the same graph for a,b and so forth).

```
     SSID      Time  RSSI
0     a  13:14:42   -33
1     a  13:14:46   -30
2     a  13:14:49   -31
3     a  13:14:52   -31
4     a  13:14:55   -35
..  ...       ...   ...
64    b  13:15:43   -58
65    b  13:15:46   -56
66    b  13:15:50   -65
67    b  13:15:53   -52
68    b  13:15:57   -65
```

What I've written plots every point together in one line, but how can I plot them on the same graph, but have them separated based on the identifier?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temp = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(temp)
plt.show
```

Thank you!

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.lineplot(data=temp, x='Time', y='RSSI', hue='SSID')`.

Answer (score 0):

- reshape so that SSID are columns
- simple pandas `plot()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""     SSID      Time  RSSI
0     a  13:14:42   -33
1     a  13:14:46   -30
2     a  13:14:49   -31
3     a  13:14:52   -31
4     a  13:14:55   -35
64    b  13:15:43   -58
65    b  13:15:46   -56
66    b  13:15:50   -65
67    b  13:15:53   -52
68    b  13:15:57   -65"""), sep="\s+")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[10,6])
df.set_index(["SSID","Time"]).unstack(0).droplevel(0,1).plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]